# Opening UCS-2le File With Vim on Windows

Tags: vim, encoding, ucs2

I'm using Vim 7.3 on WinXP.  I use XML files that are generated by an application at my work which writes them with UCS-2le encoding.  After reading several articles on encoding at the vim wiki I found the following advice given, namely to set my file encoding in vimrc:

```
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8
```

The file in question has FF EE as the first characters (confirmed viewing with HxD), but Vim doesn't open it properly.  I *can* open my UCS-2le files properly with this in my vimrc:

```
set fileencodings=ucs-2le, utf-8
```

But now my UTF-8 files are a mess!

Any advice how to proceed?  I typically run Gvim without behave MSwin (if that matters).  I use very few plugins.  My actual vimrc setting regarding file encodings are:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,ucs-2le,latin1
```

The entry for ucs-2le in the third spot seems to make no difference.  As I understand it, the first entry (set encoding) is the encoding Vim uses internally in its buffer, while the second (set fileencodings) deals with the encoding of the file when vim reads and writes it.  So, it seems to me that since the file has a byte order mark, ucs-bom as the first entry in setfileencodings should catch it. As far I can tell, it seems that vim doesn't recognize that this file is 16 bytes per character.

Note: I can/do solve the problem in the meantime by manually setting the file encoding when I open my ucs-2le files:

```
edit ++enc=ucs2-le
```

Cheers.

Comment: Hm, this works for me with your settings mentioned last. Vim 7.3, Windows Vista, default config. Does `:echo has('iconv')` yield `1` (i.e., can you convert between character sets)?

Comment: Hi.  `:echo has('iconv')` yields `0`.  I can convert between character sets, though, as `edit ++enc=ucs2-le` works.  Viewing `:version` yields `+iconv\dyn` in the list of included features.

Comment: Actually, some further clues (I don't know if this is helpful): I can't actually convert a utf8 file to ucs-2le, if I do so from scratch by creating a new utf8 file, setting the encoding to ucs-2le with `set fileencoding=ucs-2le`, and trying to save it (fails).  But I _can_ open a ucs-2le file, read it in the buffer after using the `:edit ++enc=ucs2-le` command, and then, with edits made, save it as (still) a ucs-2le file -- confirmed by viewing the file with a hex editor.  This doesn't really make sense to me though.  At least it demonstrates more problems with ucs2 encoding!

Comment: Some excitement but no joy at finding this post: [link] (http://superuser.com/questions/207264/gvim-utf-8-in-windows), also described in the "extra files" noted at vim.org: [link] (http://www.vim.org/download.php).  I put the iconv.dll in my vim73 folder but I still cannot create a utf-8 from scratch and write it as ucs2-le. :( sigh.  Not a huge deal.  I sometimes view but rarely edit these files - it would be nice not to have to use the `:edit ++enc=ucs2-le` every time I open such a file to view its contents.  For all other purposes I use either ansii or utf8 files without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.  I am not sure what I did but the fixes noted are working perfectly now to read and write my UCS-2 files - though for unknown reason not immediately (did I just restart Vim?).  I could try to reverse the fixes to see which one was the critical change but here's what I've done (see also my comments on Jul 27 above):

- Put AutoFenc.vim plugin in my plugins folder (automatically detects file encoding ([AutoFenc.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2721)).
- Added iconv.dll and new version of libintl.dll to my vim73 folder ([Vim.org](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc))
- Edited vimrc as below

vimrc now contains (the last bits just make it easier to see what's happening with file encodings by showing the file encoding in the status line):

```
"use utf-8 by default
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,ucs-2le,latin1

"always show status line
set laststatus=2

"show encoding in status line http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Show_fileencoding_and_bomb_in_the_status_line
if has("statusline")
 set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%{\"[\".(&fenc==\"\"?&enc:&fenc).((exists(\"+bomb\")\ &&\ &bomb)?\",B\":\"\").\"]\ \"}%k\ %-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
endif
```

And all is well.

Comment: Just a final note about changing the file encoding.  Many web pages give instructions on using Vim to change the encoding for a file with a command invoking the filename and the iconv library.  If the file is already in the Vim buffer then it is also very easy: `:set fileencoding=utf8` and if there is a byte order mark that needs to be removed then additionally `:setlocal nobomb`  With these commands I have been able to change my UCS files to UTF8 files (when/if needed).

Comment: I was struggling with finding the mentioned dll's in your answer, then I found [this](http://t60193.editors-vim-development.editortalk.info/bug-gvim-7-0-205-on-xp-can-not-display-ucs-2-t60193.html), I only added the two lines `set fileencodings+=ucs-2le` and `set encoding=utf-8` in `vimrc` and that solved the problem for me.